# Characters using outrageous code phrases for ordinary activities

Tags: story-identification

I remember exceedingly little about this story. I think it was some sort of sci-fi.

1. Written circa 2000 +/- 10.
2. Two main characters are young adult males in modern day USA.
3. When telecommunicating (phone? email? text?) they use a particularly absurd slang, where the code phrases sound blatantly criminal. For example, if one wants the other to go to the bar, he might say "Let's assassinate the President tonight".

Comment: What about this story (set in the present day) was sci-fi?

Comment: FWIW, if it is JDatE, it's more Fantasy than Science Fiction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might be the 2007 book (and 2012 film) *[John Dies at the End](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1857440.John_Dies_at_the_End)* as per the dialogue mentioned on the TV Tropes page for [Spy Speak](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SpySpeak):

> "Hello?"
>  
>   "Dave? This is John. Your pimp says bring the crack shipment tonight, or he'll be forced to stick you. Meet him where we buried the Korean whore. The one without the goatee." 
>   That was code. It meant "Come to my place as soon as you can, it's important." Code, you know, in case the phone was bugged. 
>   "John, it's three in the—" 
>   "—Oh, and don't forget, tomorrow is the day we kill the President." 
>   *Click* 
>   He was gone. That last part was code for, "Stop and pick me up some cigarettes on the way."

The movie script has almost the exact same exchange.

Comment: That's the one, thanks.