# Film where a dropout takes drugs to fight demons

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a weird film with people using drugs in order to access some kind of super power to fight evil.

My brain cannot put a title on it because the title was not related to the movie, and the only description of the movie I can think of is, "shooting up wasabi, fighting a frozen chicken meat demon, matrix dodges, gunfire, arachnids, the end of the world, a dog catches the ball, the end".

The dog catching the ball was an important part of the movie, or perhaps eating it.

I saw it around 2008. It was Direct to DVD, not a theater film, a [Z movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_movie). Psychedelic.

If Raoul Duke (Johnny Depp) from Las Vegas Parano took drugs after reading H. P. Lovecraft, with *The Matrix* playing on the TV, while he was petting his dog, the dream that would result would be the movie.

Comment: May I ask why the downvote? Disclaimer. When you see the movie the quoted sentence make total sense and is the perfect pitch. There was no story no real construction

Comment: Your description, while colourful, isn't especially enlightening. Who (or what) are the people doing all of these things?

Comment: It,s your last 2-1/2 paragraphs that rankle me.  Have you gotten into the spirit of the movie and now believe proper language is optional?

Comment: A lot of the question just doesn’t make sense, so I downvoted.

Comment: @Stormblessed, the film doesn't make sence. And does not try to. Mounty python and las vegas parano made sence.

Comment: I hope not to cause offense, but doing a spell-check on this would have significantly improved reception.

Comment: Technically, this is a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142506/characters-using-outrageous-code-phrases-for-ordinary-activities/142510#142510, but the questions are very different.

Comment: @Stormblessed I've read the novel. The way the question is worded may not be very proper in general but it makes it incredibly easy to identify the story if you're familiar with it, so IMHO it makes some amount of sense to keep it this way.

Comment: Especially the last paragraph.

Comment: I didn't remember the spie speak. In fact, If I was reading the dupe question not knowing the answer I could not connect them in anyway without having to rewatch the movie.  @Cubic, did the code phrase "_Let's assassinate the President tonight_" had a connection to the book for you? Did you remember any of the spie speak?

Comment: I agree. The questions are very different...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[John Dies at the End](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Dies_at_the_End_(film))*. It's a bit later than you remember, being released to video on demand in 2012, in theaters in 2013, and then to DVD later that year.

> David Wong, a slacker, recalls confronting a zombie skinhead whom he beheaded one year prior and wonders whether an axe that had its handle and head replaced over time is still the same axe. In the present day, he meets with small time reporter, Arnie Blondestone, to recount the supernatural events that plagued the small, undisclosed city David lives in.

.....

> A frantic, incoherent John calls Dave, demanding he come over at once. At John's apartment, David finds a syringe containing a black-colored drug, oblivious to a bizarre creature only John can see. John tells David that the drug, "Soy Sauce", given to him by Marley, grants inhuman knowledge when taken, along with dumping the user in alternate dimensions and timestreams, as demonstrated by a past version of John calling present Dave.

.....

> The two step through a portal to an alternate Earth. Disciples of Korrok greet them as "chosen ones" and present a brutal utilitarian society, where dissenters are horribly maimed by Korrok's monsters. The duo are brought before Korrok, who plans to devour them, absorb their knowledge to conquer their dimension. John tries to activate the bomb, but fumbles. Bark Lee [Amy's dog], who followed the two, grabs the bomb and flings himself into Korrok, detonating it and destroying the two of them.

Found with a search for *film dropout takes drug to fight monsters*

Comment: Ho it's soy sauce. Quick question You have seen it or did the question made enought sense?

Comment: @xdtTransform: Truthfully, I haven't seen it, but my Google search popped up the name, and I thought, "Hey, that thing has a meat monster. Does it have a dog?"

Comment: I was pretty sure it was connected to a Japanese condiment. I went for Wasabi and my search revolved around it. It was in fact Soy sauce.

Comment: It is amazing how a slight variation in the search term can come up with very different results. I'll typically start with a very detailed query, and then start subtracting things.